# How to run multiple commands in sequence in terminal if they are very long commands?

Tags: terminal

I need to run many commands on sequence like 5 or 10. But they all deal with paths so they are very long like 90 characters each so && won't work probably.

Is there any workaround ?

I want then to only run after the one finished and succeeded.

Comment: Short answer, most likely, yes (as a shell script) - but more information would help a lot. Are the commands all know? Do they have common sections? Could you update the question to include a sample of the commands?

Comment: 90 characters is not very long at all. What do you mean by "won't work probably"? Have you tried it? Did it not work? I see absolutely no reason for this not to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them line by line in a shell script, ending each line with a `\` (which will escape the newline):

```
#!/bin/bash

command1 /very/long/path/to/directory && \
command2 /another/very/long/path/to/directory && \
command3 /and/another/very/long/path/to/another/directory && \
echo "Command sequence finished succesfully"
```